# Is arduino starter kit disappearing?

Tags: arduino-uno

It seems they stop the production of arduino starter kit (official), it's hard to find it on pro website.
Is there an other very good starter kit to start ? I mean I would like to try everything on small given project before starting my own project.

Comment: I haven't seen any information about the official starter kit being discontinued. Did you read an announcement about it?

Comment: it's out of stock in all the pro website I checked for a while now.

Comment: I suspect they're just struggling to keep up with demand. There are many alternative starter kits available from various sellers, depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, it's still available on the [arduino store](http://store.arduino.cc/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=2&products_id=185) website

Comment: Yes I know but you can only pay with paypal ..

Comment: AFAIK, Paypal accepts plain credit card payments even without an account, if that is your issue

Answer (score 1):

Make has one: [Getting Started with Arduino Kit v3.0](http://www.makershed.com/Getting_Started_with_Arduino_Kit_v3_0_p/msgsa.htm)

Comment: Can somebody confirm me it's a good kit ?

Comment: I can. Its got everything you need to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I recommmend you this one: [Beginner Learning Kit for Arduino](http://www.icstation.com/product_info.php?products_id=3515#.VI-s8clGTQs), but they do not add the code here.